# Has anyone used Cumulus CI with Bamboo for Salesforce Continuous Integraiton?

Tags: continuous-integration

I am trying to set up Cumulus CI with Bamboo for salesforce continues integration. Cumulus CI works well with codeship but wants to configure it using Bamboo

Comment: can you add some more details and be specific on where you got stuck or what help you are looking for

Comment: Are you just looking to swap out Jenkins for Bamboo in the Cumulus CI Architecture?

Comment: Yes, But I am using Codeship at a moment. I would like to swap Codeship with Bamboo.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: I want to set up salesforce continues integration. Currently, I am using Codeship but wants to replace bamboo with codeship but also using cumulus CI for creating manage package.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't built an integration with Bamboo but the entire project is in Github and open source.  If you're interested in building an integration I'd be happy to help guide you in what changes would be needed.  It'd mostly be modifications to the build scripts and Python scripts in CumulusCI.

Another option you might want to consider is CumulusCIJenkins which was just created to make it easier to set up most everything you need in Jenkins with a Docker image and jenkins-job-builder for easily (~10 lines) configuring your jobs for CumulusCI.

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCIJenkins